# Protobuf-net dynamic types in a load-balanced system

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm using protobuf-net in an application that does a lot of binary serialization of objects from (for all intents and purposes) 3rd party dlls. As a result, I can't use the [Proto-] attributes on the contracts themselves, and I'm instead using the RuntimeTypeModel to prepare the serializer at runtime as it encounters new types. Example serializer wrapper:

```
public static class ProtobufSerializer
{
    public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj)
    {
         PrepareSerializer(typeof(T));
         ProtoBuf.Serialize(memoryStream, obj); 
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] bytes)
    {
         PrepareSerializer(typeof(T));
         ProtoBuf.Serialize(memoryStream, obj); 
    }
}
```

Where we can safely assume that `PrepareSerializer` is capable of preparing `RuntimeTypeModel` to serialize any given type. I'm having some issues with the deserialization of objects where I have to leverage `DynamicType=true` though. For instance, given the following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Name {get;}
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Bar Bar {get;set;}

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(Type t)
    {
        PrepareSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Baz {get;set;}
}
```

The `PrepareSerializer` method essentially would use a surrogate and generate a model roughly equivalent to:

```
// registered surrogate for IFoo
[ProtoContract]
public class IFooSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType=true)]
    public object Value

    [OnSerializing]
    public void OnSerializing(Type t)
    {
        PrepareSerializer(this.Value.GetType());
    }
}
```

Where `Value` is set by the implicit converters to equal the instance of IFoo. This works fine during serialize (where the event is fired and gives me a chance to prepare the serializer for the specific interface implementation type). It would also work fine in a non-distributed system where I would have to run through a serialize method before ever trying to deserialize that type. During deserialization in a distributed system though, where the current node has never seen Foo before, the ProtoBuf.Serializer throws an `InvalidOperationException` complaining about a lack of serializer for type `Bar` before it runs the Foo.OnDeserializing event (giving me a chance to tell it how to deserialize Bar).

Is there any way to attach a hook to ensure my code is given a chance to know about 'Foo' before protobuf-net complains about a lack of serializers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried exactly this situation, but: in order to allow some flexibility, all `Type` storage and rehydration goes via the `TypeModel.DynamicTypeFormatting` event; so, you *could* in theory hook this event on `RuntimeTypeModel.Default`, with something like:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.DynamicTypeFormatting += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.FormattedName != null) { // meaning: rehydrating
        lock(SomeSyncLock) {
            if(NotYetKnown(args.FormattedName))
                Prepare(args.FormattedName);
        }
    }
};
```

The *intent* of this API is to allow you to control how types are resolved, but... I guess it would work for this too?

---

I can, however, get behind the idea of an event that is more deliberately targeted at the first time a new `Type` is seen, essentially replacing / supplementing the "apply default behaviour" code. I don't think it exists *today*, though.

Comment: This works splendidly. I was looking at this event earlier to optimize the size of dynamic types but hadn't considered it for this purpose. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcGravell if we add a handler for this DynamicTypeFormatting event to RuntimeTypeModel.Default - will it be called for absolutely all serialized objects, or are there other instances of RuntimeTypeModel that we need to hook into? Also, can you confirm "all Type storage and rehydration goes via" this and not only dynamic types?

Comment: We have implemented the above to omit the assembly version from the serialized stream, but it looks like some types are getting written with default names, so I'm wondering if this may ever get skipped.

Comment: @zvolkov if you have an example where it does something odd, I'd love to see it over at github